My plugin's description is not displayed in WordPress Admin's Plugins Interface
I have an issue with my plugin's description. When I go to the Admin interface in WordPress → Plugins → Installed Plugins, I see all the other plugin's description, except the one that I developed for this new plugin.
Bear in mind that I added a description in the plugin's main PHP file, as the norm said :
/**
 * Plugin Name: Tatata
 * Plugin URI: https://link
 * Description : it makes a b c d
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: WebTips
 * Author URI: https://link
 * Text Domain: tata
 * Domain Path: languages/
**/

Since I added plugin translations I think, the description won't display. What can be the reason guys?
I don't know what to try either, because everything is working well in the plugin.

Description : - There should not be space before colon :.

Thank you, that was the only issue I had

I think Nilambar Sharma Answer it what your looking for , there is just small typo its Description: not Description : also make sure to have the php tag at the top of the comment to accept file-level PHPDoc DocBlock Refer to WordPress Documentation for more info . Header Requirements- WordPress Plugin Handbook
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Tatata
 * Plugin URI: https://link
 * Description: it makes a b c d
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: WebTips
 * Author URI: https://link
 * Text Domain: tata
 * Domain Path: languages/
**/



Yes, that was the only reason. Thank you ! (for the PHP tag, I added it, I just didn't show it here in my code).

Your most welcome mate , good luck developing your plugin.
